# Php how to correctly use return function?

Tags: php, function, return

Hello I have a problem with this function I want to show the result of the function to put in a variable and send it to the database but it does not show me anything you can see in the example in the Second Block when I added **echo** its show me but I don't know how to get that result out I did use **return** but it gave a different result

```
$fullname = "Ayoub Chafik" ;

function orderID($data){
    $AKK = "AK". date('YmdHis');
    $string = strtoupper($data);
    $strs=explode(" ",$string);
    foreach($strs as $str)
    $str[0];

}
// I want to see resulte here of this function
   echo orderID($fullname) ;


?>
```

This is the second Block

```
<?php

$fullname = "Ayoub Chafik" ;

function orderID($data){
    echo $AKK = "AK". date('YmdHis');
    $string = strtoupper($data);
    $strs=explode(" ",$string);
    foreach($strs as $str)
    echo $str[0];

}

echo orderID($fullname) ;


?>
```

Comment: Add `return $str[0];` at the end of the function

Comment: Your `$str[0]` is under `foreach` loop, it return the first element value. It won't continue the loop. You can create variable and store the values & at the end return the new varaible

Comment: when I do it, it changes the value of the variable $str[0] that is AC to 0

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Split the names by first and last then save into database?

Comment: @giolliano 
yeah split the first letter of the first name and the last name + a code and save them in the database

Comment: @AyoubChafik Hi I submit an example code. I'm getting the output `AC` as you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explained in comment you store it in a variable and return it. Check below example. Also it is a good practice to open the `{}` even its only one line for more readability.

```
$fullname = "Ayoub Chafik" ;

function orderID($data) {
    $string  = strtoupper($data);
    $strs    = explode(" ", $string);
    $results = '';

    foreach($strs as $str) {
        $results .= $str[0];
    }

    return $results;
}

echo orderID($fullname) ;
```

Comment: can explain to me if you have time the dot. before the = sign role in the function ?

Comment: It is similar to `$results = $results . $str[0]`. String concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Some examples varying output based on your code sample.

```
$fullname = "Ayoub Chafik";
function orderID($data){
    $string = strtoupper($data);
    $strs=explode(" ",$string);
    foreach($strs as $str) {
    return $str;
    }
}
echo orderID($fullname) ;
// output "AYOUB"
function _orderID($data){
    $return = false;
    $string = strtoupper($data);
    $strs=explode(" ",$string);
    foreach($strs as $str) {
    $return = $str;
    }
    return $return;
}
echo _orderID($fullname) ;
// output "CHAFIK"
function _orderID_($data){
    $return = [];
    $string = strtoupper($data);
    $strs=explode(" ",$string);
    foreach($strs as $str) {
    array_push($return,$str);
    }
    return json_encode($return);
}
echo _orderID_($fullname) ;
// output ["AYOUB","CHAFIK"]
```

check the above examples on [PHP SandBox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8316b7a5bd3deba9e6f95c5f8ab37aa57e395871)